# HTML код в textarea

Tags: jquery, html, textarea

Добрый день.
Возможно ли в textarea приминить HTML?

Например, в textarea есть текст:

```
AB<span color='red'>C</span>
```

И нужно чтобы к "C" пременился указанный стиль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. Но есть [contenteditable](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/contenteditable).